# URL Rewrite - Rewrite all path and subpath to one page

Tags: url, overrides

Is it possible to rewrite a 'general' path to one page.

Ex.

suppose I want to rewrite all pages that contains

- mage.local.com/brands/*

**to:**

- mage.local.com/brands/brands.html

There is any way to accomplish this

Answer (score 3):

I could not test it, but the from-tag of rewrites is matched via regular expression, so it should be possible to match all pages, except the brands.html

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <name>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/brands/(?!brands\.html)[a-zA-Z0-9]*#]]></from>
            <to>/brands/brands.html</to>
        </name>
    </rewrite>
</global>
```